# Dunkirk's Time Measures

Tags: dunkirk

In the beginning of Dunkirk, we read

> The mole, 1 week
>
> The sea, 1 day
>
> The air, 1 hour

What are the times here? Do they represent how long each timeline is in the movie until its end?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, that’s pretty much how it is:

- Spitfires only have an hour of fuel
- it takes somewhat longer to sail across the channel and back again
- it takes a lot longer to evacuate half a million troops from a beach...

There's a certain amount of skill in terms of the script to bring these timelines together on-screen without it being too jarring to the viewer.